# Use UTF16-LE with BOM encoding in Text File Output in PDI Kettle

Tags: kettle, utf-16, pdi

I am very new to PDI kettle. I have a requirement where client want UTF16-LE with BOM encoding in the output text file/csv file. But in the 'content' tab of 'Text File Output Step' i can see only following options UTF-16,UTF-16LE,UTF-16BE.

Is there some other setting from which i can set the character code to UTF16-LE with BOM.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10, JDK 1.8_92, Pentaho Data-Integration 6.1.0-196

[image]

What is your environment?

Comment: PDI 5.20 as well has both encodings.